# MySQL (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)"

Tags: django

I couldn't access to MySQL since yesterday.

```
> mysql -u root -p

Enter password: 

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I've tried several things to fix, but don't have any clue yet.

- MacOS Mojave (10.14.3)
- Django

1. First Try

```
❯ find / -name mysql.sock 
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied 
find: /usr/local/var/mysql: Permission denied 
  ….
 
❯ mysql -u root -p mysql S/var/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock 
mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew) Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
```

I could see some messages, but can not access to MySQL.

2. Second try

I found mysql.sock file in "/var/mysql/mysql.sock"
So I edited my.cnf file, but it didn't work.

```
❯ vi /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
 
# my.cnt  
[client]  
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock  
[mysqld]  
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

❯ ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
ln: /var/mysql/mysql.sock: File exists
```

And there are other informations to try to fix.

```
> ❯ ls -l /tmp/mysql.sock
lrwxr-xr-x  1 seungholee  wheel  31  8 30 18:45 /tmp/mysql.sock -> /usr/local/bin/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Is the MySQL process running at all? `ps aux | grep mysql` (or `ps aux | grep mariadb` if you're running MariaDB)

Comment: Also, since you've apparently installed Mysql via Homebrew, have you tried `brew services start mysql`?

Comment: ```ps aux | grep mysql```, returned ```joeylee       64591   0.0  0.0  4269044    676 s000  R+    4:46PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysql```

Comment: I tried and it returned ```❯ brew services start mysql```
```Service `mysql` already started, use `brew services restart mysql` to restart.```

Comment: Well, try restarting it?

Comment: Yes, I restarted ```brew services restart mysql```. but still failed to run mysql.server.